# json getting a particular language

Tags: javascript, json

If i have a JSON with phrases in different languages:

```
var lang = {
    'topic' : {
        'en' : 'Topic',
        'et' : 'Teema',
        'fi' : 'Aihe'
    },
    'MainPage' : {
        'en' : 'Main page',
        'et' : 'Pealeht',
        'fi' : 'Pääsivu'
    }//,
    //...etc
};
```

How to define a function for choosing a particular language:

```
function getText(lang, langKey) {
    //???????
    return langJson;
}
```

that outputs the same phrases like:

```
getText(lang, 'en'); //outputs {topic:'Topic',MainPage:'Main page',..}
getText(lang, 'et'); //outputs {topic:'Teema',MainPage:'Pealeht',..}
getText(lang, 'fi'); //outputs {topic:'Aihe',MainPage:'Pääsivu',..}
```

All the best: I

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically you have to go through the whole `lang` object and *pick* the value for the correct language.

`Object.keys` will return an `Array` containing the keys of your initial `lang` object.
You can use those to create a new object.
You could use a for loop to iterate over those keys and add the corresponding value to the resulting object, but I like to use `reduce` to do so:

```
function getText(lang, langKey) {
  return Object.keys(lang).reduce(function(re, key) {
    re[key] = lang[key][langKey];
    return re;
  }, {})
}
```